# Can somebody please explain this statement (about the greenhouse effect)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, green-chemistry

"Methane is a potent gas and **over a period of 20 years has a 72 times greater effect on warming the atmosphere than carbon dioxide**.
Due to my limited english, i am failing to understand how timeline has anything to do with the effect of a gas on the greenhouse effect. I think it has to do with the half life of the gas in the atmoshpere. Maybe methane is broken down more readily than CO2 and the whole thing means that if they remained in the atmosphere for the same amount of time, methane will do a greater damage. Am i right ?

Answer (score 5):

"Methane has a large effect (24 times as strong as carbon dioxide per unit mole) for a brief period (having an estimated lifetime of 8.9±0.6 years in the atmosphere),[12] whereas carbon dioxide has a small effect for a long period (over 100 years). Because of this difference in effect and time period, the global warming potential of methane over a 20-year time period is 72."[ [Wikipedia in 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Atmospheric_methane&oldid=781957447#Methane_as_a_greenhouse_gas), quoting [Jain, Briegleb et al](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000JGR...10520773J) ].

Simplified, that means:

- $\ce{CH4}$ has a shorter half-life in the atmosphere than $\ce{CO2}$, reducing its effect as a green-house gas over time, **but**
- $\ce{CH4}$ is so much *more* potent in retaining heat than $\ce{CO2}$ that this more than compensates for its short lifetime, making $\ce{CH4}$ a stronger green-house gas over the long term.

Comment: And so if I understand correctly even though methane is present as $0.00018$% and $\ce{CO2}$ at 0.04% the 72 times is equivalent to $\approx 0.01$% $\ce{CO2}$, so a slight increase in methane in the future can be very significant.

Comment: Lets say that we have 100 cm3 of methane and 100 cm3 of CO2. Suppose that methane decomposes in 5 seconds, CO2 in 60 seconds , that methane is more potent than CO2 but not potent enough to have a greater effect on global warming over the course of 60 seconds. If it remained in the atmosphere for 60 seconds then it would do the greater overall effect on global warming. Is this model correct ? (Assume that the half lives of both methane and CO2 are as stated above and that all the other ir-realistic values are true).

Comment: Remember that the time quoted, ~9 yr,  is the *half-life* of methane. The half-life of CO2, ~27 yr, is given at http://euanmearns.com/the-half-life-of-co2-in-earths-atmosphere-part-1/. You'd need to calculate the exponential decay of each these greenhouse gases and then multiply the CH4 by ~24 to account for its greater effectiveness in retaining IR.

Comment: Sir you are talking to someone with fairly basic understanding in this area so it would help if we used a simple model like the one above to discuss this subject. Is my model (and the result which i obtained from it) correct ? Note : My result from that model is that CO2 has a greater overall effect in one minute because : 1- Methane decays more quickly than CO2. 2- Methane isnt potent enough to have a greater overall effect in one minute. But in the first five seconds, methane was causing the greater effect.is this true ?

Comment: No, it's wrong. To understand why, you need to learn about gradual, exponential decay. In your model, the methane does not disappear in 5 seconds, it's halved in five seconds.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The factor 24 is confusing because it is based on amount, whereas the 72 is based on mass. The instant (mass-based) global warming potential of methane would be calculated as 66, still lower than 72, which is surprising.

Answer (score 4):

The ["Global Warming Potential"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_warming_potential) is a relative measure of how much one gram of given substance affects infrared absorption compared to one gram of carbon dioxide, given the current composition of the atmosphere.

> [OP] i am failing to understand how timeline has anything to do with the effect of a gas on the greenhouse effect. I think it has to do with the half life of the gas in the atmoshpere. Maybe methane is broken down more readily than CO2 and the whole thing means that if they remained in the atmosphere for the same amount of time, methane will do a greater damage.

Yes, that is the gist. Methane has a half-life of about 10 years. If you release 1 g of methane into the atmosphere, the effect over the next 20 years is estimated to be similar to releasing 72 g of carbon dioxide.

On the other hand, if you look at the effect over the next million years, the carbon dioxide will [stick around](https://www.nature.com/articles/climate.2008.122), but the methane is mostly gone after the first hundred years, so the GWP of methane over this longer time span will be much lower (by about a factor of 100,000).

If you look into the literature, you will find that there is no estimate for the half-life of carbon dioxide because it is stable in the current atmosphere. Mechanisms for its removal rely on reactions with solids and liquids on the surface of the earth, and their rates depend on what is going on at the surface and below it (temperature, pH of oceans, living organisms, human activity, etc.). Methane, on the other hand, reacts with oxygen and other species in the atmosphere, turning it into other gases (many of which have their own GWP).

One should note that GWP's are revised continually, with new data available and adjusting to the current composition of the atmosphere.